# Google news search results annoying and confusing

Tags: google-search, google-news

I'm looking for latest updates of my favorite YouTuber, Kathryn Morgan. So I googled her and in Web results, I got what I intended. But when I googled her in News Search, the results like this:

[[image: Sorry Katie, it's not yours[1]]

I know that the results were confusing, as there are a lot of people named either "Kathryn" or  "Morgan" but not both full name (like the ballet YouTuber).
The same case when I googled "Jodie Holmes" in Google News Search:

[image: What! Benedict Cumberbatch instead of Aiden's sister?!]

So the results when I googled Jodie in News Search were a lot of about Benedict Cumberbatch, Jodie Whittaker, Sherlock Holmes, and a lot people named Jodie.

What happened in my case?

Comment: No, sir. Just plain name without quotes

Comment: Yes, it works, but the results sometimes still not accurate, because there are also a lot of people named "Kathryn Morgan" (one of them is a Youtuber).

Comment: Yes, I tested with News tab in Google Search

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be more specific in your search terms.

The first thing to do, if you're looking for news about a specific person, is to put their name in quotes.

Next, if that still finds too many results with the same name, you need to add keywords that will narrow your search. So, for your case, `youtube` would be a good one. This person also seems to be known for beauty and makeup tutorials, so `beauty` and similar keywords should help.

Finally, you may need to use keyword negation. My wife shares a name with a celebrity chef out west, so if I want to search Google News for my wife I need to include `-chef` and `-california` in the search terms.

Comment: @pnuts: Yes, I believe so. A Google News archive search is identical to using the "News" tab from the regularly Google search results.

Comment: I'm in Indonesia sir

Comment: @BagasSanjaya - Please don't assume all SE participants are *sirs* (male).  Thank you.